# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator save to XML

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I've set up a model with (Task) and in my way to understand Core Data I've come as far as  this: adding three items to a context:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *m = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *p = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:m];

//    NSPersistentStore *pp = [p addPersistentStoreWithType:NSXMLStoreType configuration:nil URL: options:<#(NSDictionary *)#> error:<#(NSError *__autoreleasing *)#>

NSManagedObjectContext *c = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[c setPersistentStoreCoordinator:p];
Task *t = [[Task alloc] init];
t.label = @"Test Item";
[c insertObject:t];
[c insertObject:t];
[c insertObject:t];
```

How can I now serialize this context to a XML file? Thanks.

EDIT: seems like NSXMLStoreType is not available in the iPhone!

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look in the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.h` file, you'll see these lines...

```
// Persistent store types supported by Core Data:
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSSQLiteStoreType NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 3_0);
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSXMLStoreType NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, NA);
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSBinaryStoreType NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 3_0);
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSInMemoryStoreType NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 3_0);
```

Notice that for most of these store types we see `NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 3_0)` This means that those store type are available in Mac OS 10.4 and up and also in iOS 3.0 and up.

However, for `NSXMLStoreType`, we instead see `NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, NA)`.  This means that `NSXMLStoreType` is available for Mac OS 10.4 and up and Not Available for any iOS.

In the past it has been possible to unlock that .h file, modify this NSString to make this store type available and write your own implementation of this store type, but I have not been able to actually make this work.